# Div id persistence in backbone views

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, marionette

Lets say I have a backbone view, lets name it `view1`, which renders a template: `template1` with a div having an `id="first"`

Now, in another view, lets name it `view2`, I render another template: `template2` where I again (by mistake) name a div with `id="first"`

**Question** - Will this cause an error if I don't render `template1` and `template2` together on the same page (I am using Marionette's show() function). In other words, do template 'divs' persist on the DOM?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: no problem, for the moment till the are not on the same page, but as soon as possible modify your id.

Comment: Thanks, will be careful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not cause any issue. Simply template2 will replace template1 kind off.

Comment: not really : `if I don't render template1 and template2 together on the same page`